# Failed to resolve sdks in libs folder Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

My project level gradle is in groovy.
I have replaced the

```
repositories {
flatDir {
    dirs 'libs'
}
}
```

To

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }}
```

I have multiple aar/jar in libs folder and I have been using this to integrate all from build gradle

```
fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '**/*.aar')
    .each { File file ->
        dependencies.add("implementation", [name: file.name.lastIndexOf('.').with {
            it != -1 ? file.name[0..<it] : file.name
        }, ext : 'aar'])
    }
```

Now I get the error for all aar files

```
Failed to resolve: "aar name"
```